# need to download from eMule on linux

Tags: linux, emule

i have a dedicated ubuntu server and would like it to download files from emule....but it has no gui.

i am looking for a command line tool like rtorrent but that handles e2dk links.

Answer (score 1):

Check for [AMuleCMD](http://wiki.amule.org/index.php/AMuleCMD).

Another option would be to connect to the server with ***ssh -X***, and use the amule GUI remotely - but that way you will need to keep the connection open.